# Netty's data represenatation inside ChannelPipeline?

Tags: java, netty

I am learning **Netty framework**. As far as I know it is roughly built around two components, `ByteBuffer` (for low level data representation) and `Channel` (for transmission of ByteBuffers in the wire). I was looking through Netty examples which is bundled with it (Netty 3.2). And I came to simple `Telnet` program which was given below. Here I do not quite understand the order of pipeline, in which the data coming into `ChannelPipeline` was first decoded and again encoded and after that forwarded to handler, which means data type inside `(Channel)` `ChannelPipeline` is *binary* (correct me If I am wrong), but I thought it would be *text*. What is the reason of favouring *binary* over *text* representation inside `Channel (ChannelPipeline)`?

```
package org.jboss.netty.example.telnet; 

public class TelnetServerPipelineFactory implements
    ChannelPipelineFactory {

public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    // Create a default pipeline implementation.
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channel.pipeline();

    // Add the text line codec combination first,
    pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
            8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

    // and then business logic.
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new TelnetServerHandler());

    return pipeline;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems confusing at first. The normal path for a message passing through the pipeline should be as follows.

1. Message Arrives at the socket as a stream of bytes.
2. They are decoded by the StringDecoder and hence the byte stream get converted to a String.
3. The string gets passed on to the TelnetServerHandler and then you can play with it as you like.

So where does the **encoder** come into play ? **Why is it even there in the pipeline and that too before the TelnetServerHandler** ? Will it not encode the String back to a stream of bytes ?

So basically in Netty, the handlers are of two types. They can be either downstream handlers or upstream handlers or even both.
Basically Downstream is when a pipeline is sending something to a remote. Upstream is when it is reading something from a remote. So the decoders are upstream handlers and they will intercept the data coming in from the remote i.e. outside.

Encoders are downstream handlers and they intercept data that the server sends to the remote. So in case you want to send a string from your TelnetServerHandler to outside world i.e. your client, then that String will be encoded to ByteBuf by the StringEncoder.

Hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: @Humoyun if this does indeed solve your doubt, please mark as accepted for future reference. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry for not marking, the reason I did nor mark is that the first answer by Moh-Aw also solved my doubt on this, actually his comment ("the order does not matter" ). So I thought it would be kinda unfair marking your answer when his comment also helped before yours, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Normally decoders only handle incoming messages. They extend `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`. The encoder does not do anything with incoming messages apart from calling the next handler in the pipeline. You will have a `String` in the `TelnetServerHandler`.

Now if this handler would send a message it would be encoded (encoder extends `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter` and overwrites the `write()` method at some point) and the `ByteBuf` would be sent to the connected peer. 
The decoder does not do anything with outgoing messages. Its `write()` method just calls the next handler.

Comment: I just thought, the encoder should come after handler in the pipeline, since it is responsible for outbound data it should be last in the pipeline (correct me if I am wrong), or the order of adding does not matter

Comment: From Netty's perspective and in this scenario you first add a decoder and an encoder to the pipeline (order doesn't matter). After that you add a custom handler or in this case the `TelnetHandler` which either works with the received and decoded message or writes to the channel and invokes the encoding.